# For python 3,I keep get a string value with a new line

Tags: python, python-3.x

the error is when I enter d, and Enter a sentence: David, y r u l8
David,why\nare\nyou\nlate\n  , but I need it to return David, why are you late

```
def update_dictionary(fileName,dictionary):
try:
    a = open(fileName)
except IOError:
    print( fileName,"does not exist.")
    print("The dictionary has",len(dictionary),"entries.")
    return dictionary
with a:
    print(fileName,"loaded successfully.")
    for word in a:
        c,b = word.split(",")
        dictionary[c] = b
    print("The dictionary has",len(dictionary),"entries.")
    return dictionary
def deslang(filename,dic):
x = ""
words = filename.split(" ")
for i in range(len(words)):
    if words[i] in dic:
        words[i] = dic[words[i]]
for i in range(len(words)-1):
    x = x + words[i] + " "
x = x + words[len(words) -1]
return x

def main():
name = {}
while 1:
    u_input = input("Would you like to (a)dd words to the dictionary, (d)e-slang a sentence, or (q)uit?: ")
    if u_input == "q":
        break
    if u_input == "a":
        fileName = ""
        while len(fileName) == 0:
            fileName =  input("Enter a filename: ")
        name = update_dictionary(fileName,name)
    if u_input == "d":
        sentence = ""
        while len(sentence) == 0:
            sentence = input("Enter a sentence: ")
        print(deslang(sentence, name))
```

if **name** =="**main**":
    main()

Answer (score 1):

You need to [strip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip) the newlines off each of the dictionary lines. In other words:

```
for word in a:
    c,b = word.rstrip().split(",")
    dictionary[c] = b
```

When you iterate a file like `for word in a:`, you get a string for each line in the file, *including the newline at the end*. So, your dictionary ends up full of entries like `'y': 'why\n'` instead of `'y': 'why'`.

Answer (score 1):

You can strip the trailing newline from `word.split(",")` by calling [str.strip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html).

```
word.strip().split(",")
```

You can also use `read()` to load the contents of the file which doesn't include newlines.